# Convert boxed array to normal array?

Tags: j

Suppose I have a boxed array like;

```
┌─┬─┬─┐
│1│2│3│
└─┴─┴─┘
```

how do I covert it to a normal array such as `1 2 3`?

Comment: `<`  is for boxing, `>` for unboxing.

Comment: I’m addition to @Eelvex’s great comment, there’s also *raze* `;`. Depends on the specifics of your actual boxes array and what you want the results to look like - especially its shape.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is not clear enough to specify exactly what is the wanted behavior on higher-dimension arrays. Thus there will be two solutions, which are the most commonly wanted behaviors in this kind of situations.

The first solution is to use the builtin monadic verb [raze](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/semi) `;`, as such

```
  ]a=.<"(0) 1+i.3
+-+-+-+
|1|2|3|
+-+-+-+
  ;a
1 2 3
```

Pretty straightforward. However, it should be noted that raze has rank `_`, and that it will always produce a list, that is, it will also flatten your array:

```
  ]a=.<"(0) 1+i.2 3
+-+-+-+
|1|2|3|
+-+-+-+
|4|5|6|
+-+-+-+
  ;a
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

If you don't want that behavior, you can always use the [rank](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/quote) conjunction `"`:

```
  ;"1 a
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Alternatively, you may also want to preserve the original shape of the array, in which case the monadic verb [open](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/gt) `>` is probably what you want:

```
  ]a=.<"(0) 1+i.3
+-+-+-+
|1|2|3|
+-+-+-+
  >a
1 2 3
  ]a=.<"(0) 1+i.2 3
+-+-+-+
|1|2|3|
+-+-+-+
|4|5|6|
+-+-+-+
  >a
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Finally, you should know that it's not necessary to create an array of unboxed values to operate on them, as creating this array may lead to unwanted behavior (especially with padding):

```
  ]a=.1 2;3 4 5
+---+-----+
|1 2|3 4 5|
+---+-----+
  >a
1 2 0
3 4 5
```

Suppose I'd want to add `1` to each atom inside the boxes of `a`. Opening `a` won't do, as that will create an additional element `0` that is required for padding, which won't be removed if I rebox the lists afterwards

```
  <"1>a
+-----+-----+
|1 2 0|3 4 5|
+-----+-----+
  a -: <"1>a 
0
```

Instead, I can modify my verb "add 1" to work on boxes instead, with the conjunction [under (dual)](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/ampdot) `&.`

```
  a=.1 2;3 4 5
  1&+&.>a
+---+-----+
|2 3|4 5 6|
+---+-----+
```

Note that there is no extra padding!